# Your client does not support opening this list with windows explorer 9

Tags: sharepoint-server, explorer, internet

I have tried all the possibilities and solutions proposed on the web to resolve the issue "Your client does not support opening this list with Windows Explorer" when we try to open it from a sharepoint server in ie9. Here are the details of both the sharepoint server and the client system.

### Sharepoint Server:

OS:       Windows 2008 Server 64 Bit
Features: Desktop Experience Enabled
          Webclient is running
          Internet explorer 9 with 32 bit

### Client machine:

OS:       Windows 2008 Server R2 32 Bit
Features: Desktop Experience Enabled
          Webclient is running
          Internet explorer 9 with 32 bit

Added to Trusted Sites: https://*.microsoftonline.com
                        https://*.lync.com
                        https://*.sharepoint.com
                        https://*.outlook.com
Add to Intranet Sites: *.microsoftonline.com
                       *.lync.com
                       *.sharepoint.com
                       *.outlook.com

All the possibilities I have tried suggested on the web. But no use and I am in weired situation. Please suggest a useful solution.

Even I am not able to map a network drive to sharepoint site. But, I am able to map to a shared folder from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your client machine is also Windows server then Install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
This will work :)

Comment: Thank Manu for the response. I had installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 as you said. But the same error.